# How to delete key in etcd with revision

Tags: go, etcd

I want to delete a key in etcd while others put the key into etcd. So I want to specify the revision when delete. If key version is lower then the revision, then delete it. Otherwise do nothing.

```
// putInfoOp returns a PUT etcd operation for Info.
func putInfoOp(info Info) (clientv3.Op, error) {
    value, err := info.toJSON()
    if err != nil {
        return clientv3.Op{}, err
    }
    key := KeyAdapter.Encode(info.A, info.B)
    return clientv3.OpPut(key, value), nil
}

// deleteInfoOp returns a DELETE etcd operation for info.
func deleteInfoOp(info Info) clientv3.Op {
    return clientv3.OpDelete(KeyAdapter.Encode(
        info.A, info.B))
}

// my code
func handleinfo(info Info){
    putOp, _ := putInfoOp(info)
    _, rev, err := etcdutil.DoOpsInOneTxnWithRetry(cli, putOp)
    
    dosomething()
    
    delOp, _ := deleteInfoOp(Info) // how to delete it with rev?
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details and add code to show exactly where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

According to the library docs that feat is enabled just for `get` op

https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/76e769ce95ca0d4d0e3486712d96956260db04b8/clientv3/op.go#L231

https://github.com/etcd-io/etcd/blob/76e769ce95ca0d4d0e3486712d96956260db04b8/clientv3/op.go#L431-L440